# How to use locomotive-scroll in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, locomotive-scroll

I want to beautify my project using locomotive-scroll in my nextjs app. But I keep getting the error document is not defined. How can I solve this?

In short, this is what I need to know.

Thank you from now!

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import locomotiveScroll from "locomotive-scroll";

function App() {
  const scrollRef = React.createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const scroll = new locomotiveScroll({
      el: scrollRef.current,
      smooth: true
    });
  });

  return (
      <div className="scroll" ref={scrollRef}>
        <h1 data-scroll data-scroll-speed="3" data-scroll-position="top">
          Locomotive Scroll in React
        </h1>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to correctly use Locomotive Scroll with Next.js routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68264720/how-to-correctly-use-locomotive-scroll-with-next-js-routing)? You need to dynamically import `locomotive-scroll` inside the `useEffect`.

Comment: I had looked at this before but it gave the same error :(

Comment: Did you also remove `import locomotiveScroll from "locomotive-scroll";` at the top of the file? If you're importing and accessing `locomotive-scroll` only inside the `useEffect` you won't see the "document not defined" error.

Comment: Everything is under control now :) Thank you very much